# How do you write a function that remembers it's previous input in clojure

Tags: python, clojure

So I was reading SO and I came across a students problem that involved find the longest sequence of char while the next symbol occurs after the current one. For instance given a string of "abzbac" the output would be "abz".  This seems to be a fairly common learning assignment. Take while the input is increasing/decreasing. So I know how to do this in imperative way. You iterate keeping track of the index, see if if the current index and the next pass a predicate or not. I don't know how to do this in a functional way. My only guess is you would have to build a function that keeps track of the previous input to it, and is a predicate. In python I would think it would look like this.

```
def passTheTest(x):
    def current(y):
        temp = y == x # or w/e your comparison is
        x = y # saves state for the next go around
        return temp
```

How would you write this function in clojure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a bit of a different approach.
Let's first see that we're interested in *whether the sequence is ascending*. This isn't really a property of the individual values, but rather of *sequential pairs of values*. So if we can re-cast the problem in terms of the sequential pairs, then at each point we *have* the data we need, without state. To make those pairs, we can use `partition` to take 2 values each time but advance in steps of 1 . For example, `(partition 2 1 "abzbac")`, gives us `((\a \b) (\b \z) (\z \b) ...`

Now our usual mappings, filterings and so on work again:

```lisp
(defn longest-increasing [the-str]
  (let [pairs (partition 2 1  the-str) ;;Divide the string into the sequential pairs
        directioned (partition-by (comp neg? (partial apply compare)) pairs) ;;Group pairs by whether the second char is "higher" or "lower"
        ascending (filter #(neg? (apply compare (first %))) directioned) ;Filter out any descending sequences
        longest (apply (partial max-key count) ascending)] ;;take the longest sequence
    (clojure.string/join (cons (ffirst longest) (map second longest))))) ;;Glue it back together.
```

Answer (score 2):

I would also use reduce, but I think this is a bit clearer.

```lisp
;; rebuild a string from a vector of char
(apply str
       ;; get run from [run acc]
       (first
        (reduce
         (fn [[run acc] ele]
           ;; add to acc if ascending
           (let [acc' (if (pos? (compare ele (peek acc)))
                        (conj acc ele)
                        [ele])
                 ;; replace run if acc is longer
                 run' (max-key count run acc')]
             [run' acc']))
         [[] [Character/MAX_VALUE]]
         "abzabczab")))
```

In general, anything you can do by saving state between function calls can also be done by adding an argument that describes a prior state. The difference is that with an added argument you can do things more flexibly if needed, and if you can assume that state is not stored in functions, code is easier to understand and to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce):

```
(apply str (:max-coll
            (reduce (fn [{:keys [max-coll coll]} e]
                      (let [coll' (if (>= 0 (compare (peek coll) e) )
                                    (conj coll e)
                                    [e])]
                        {:coll coll'
                         :max-coll (if (<= (count max-coll) (count coll'))
                                     coll'
                                     max-coll)}))
                    {:max-coll [] :coll []}
                    "abyzbac")))
```